# SQL2 query has self-join in it and it is getting exception '...expected: <end>'

Tags: self-join, jcr, jackrabbit

I want to access the node using the Self-join (strictly). The type of node is nt:unstructured and I am using the below query

```
SELECT same2.*, same1.firstName AS fn 
FROM [nt:unstructured] AS same1 
JOIN [nt:unstructured] AS same2 ON ISSAMENODE(same1, same2) 
WHERE fn IS NOT NULL
```

But when I run my query given above, it is rejected with the exception:

```
javax.jcr.query.InvalidQueryException: 
Query:SELECT same2.*, same1.firstName AS fn 
FROM [nt:base] AS same1 
JOIN(*)[nt:base] AS same2 ON ISSAMENODE(same1, same2) 
WHERE fn IS NOT NULL; expected: <end>
```

I am not printing all the stacktrace.
Please help me in this regard. Thanks :)

Comment: Why are you trying to do a same-node join with the same node types? It makes sense to do a same-node join with different node types, since that's how you get access to the nodes' properties when the properties you want are defined on the different node types.

Comment: You are absolutely right that my node types are same and I could avoid self-join, but I am trying to improve my skills of writing SQL2 (using self-join) and thus doing this. I feel that self-join should be giving me the result even if the node types are same in the node.

Comment: Then I would recommend that you add a mixin (e.g., `mix:title`, `mix:mimeType`, or `mix:lastModified`) to your `nt:unstructured` nodes so you can join two *different* node types. I know you've said you're using Jackrabbit, but ModeShape automatically optimizes away any unnecessary joins, and using a same-node join with the same node types is unnecessary; perhaps Jackrabbit does, too, or perhaps this is the cause of your error.

Comment: ok thanks for your help. I will add mixin and would try with that.

Comment: thanks a lot Randall. Your comment really helped me. I added mixin type like this

@Node(jcrMixinTypes = "mix:lastModified", discriminator = false)

and it helped in making queries with self-join